Android Compose (TV) wrong focus when TTS is on
Using jetpack compose to create an APP for TV platforms and I've been trying to create a Vertical List of Horizontal Lists using a LazyColum/LazyRow having a enter Focus (first item Top Left), when enabled TalkBack the focus of the TTS goes to the closes item but the actual focus go to the Top Left
[
I create this Repository with the example code
https://github.com/daduck88/LazyColumnLazyRowsCompose/tree/main
TTS focus should follow app focus like this:


This is likely a bug; can you please provide a minimal code example by opening an issue? Thanks!

@PaulLammertsma I saw this bug report which I assigned to the accessibility team: b/335210400
